# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Veganism & Vegetarianism has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Robert Longson]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6683622496010240).

---

**November 2022 update:**

Due to staff shortage on the team, [election runner-up Rand al'Thor](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/60/rand-althor) was added to the team! Please welcome him if you see him around! ^_^

Comment: Congrats Robert!

Answer (score 3):

My thanks go to everyone who voted, whether for me or my opponents. I look forward to working with Zanna and Nic.

I'm also hoping to post more questions on Meta with ideas on how we can grow our community.

And of course if there's anything else I can do for you all, ask on Meta or raise a flag.

Answer (score 2):

### Congratulations, Robert Longson!

I'll be honest: I only nominated myself in order to have a proper election process (before Ezequiel's very late nomination which would also have guaranteed that). Although I would have been happy to serve if elected, I actually voted for you. It's good to have a new mod who's been more consistently active (than me) over the years, and perhaps also good to have someone who has V&V as their only mod site.

Good luck! See you in [TL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge) and around the site.

---

**Edit:** well, that was unexpected. Time to step up my activity here and earn this privilege.